# Selenium phantomjs (python) not redirecting to welcome page after login, page is load dynamically using dojo

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I was trying to log into a website that is loaded fuly dinamically using dojo.js scripts. On my tests I am using:

- Selenium 2.40
- Phantomjs 1.9.7 (downloaded via npm)
- Ubuntu 12.04

When I try my script with: `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Everything works fine, Firefox logins through login page `/login.do`, gets through authentication page and arrives at the landing page and everything works perfectly.

But I have to make this code for an Ubuntu Server so I can't use a GUI, when I change to: `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()`

I arrived again at `/login.do` ( print driver.current_url)
I have tried to use `WebDriverWait` and nothing happens.

Does PhantomJS for python an issue with dynamically loading pages? If not,
can I use another tool or better yet, someone knows a book or tutorial to understand XHR Requests and doing this job with requests and `urllib2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that my problem was with a `elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` line. Phantomjs seems to be very fast so I had to put a time.sleep of 2 seconds before that line, and now the script works fine. What happened is that Enter button for login wasn't clicked properly. Of course `time.sleep(2)` isn't the best way to solve it, I will change the ENTER statement into a click with xpath.